# Python: input from keyboard and print at the same time

Tags: python, keyboard-events

I want the program to read the input and print at the same time, without having to press Enter. Example:

I press: K
Console: "Your input: K" => Program does not stop

Then I press: L
Console: "Your input: KL" => Program continues

How can I do that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/curses.html#module-curses

Comment: check `curses.cbreak()`

Comment: Example of curses would be great! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458087/curses-print-characters-as-typed?r=SearchResults